# Complex Spring Boot Queries

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have multiple entities that are related to each other through complex ManytoMany, OnetoMany & ManytoOne relationships. For example, consider the entity-relationship below

[image]

Considering the ERD above, I want to retrieve all the accounts that belong to a specific solution name. Is there any way to perform such complex queries in spring boot.

I got to know Specification can be used to perform filters operation in spring boot application but I am not sure how to pull accounts based on a property that belongs to its child's child :D

Comment: I noticed `elasticsearch` in the tags. I guess you are also looking at it as option. However, as you already mentioned, how about writing custom SQL queries to do JOIN/filter/group by etc? Spring-Data-Jpa also supports it : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations. Or simply inject JdbcTemplate and write query and execute. People write SQL JOIN with several tables and they work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. All I need is to join the entities and use predicate accordingly.

```
Join<Account, ProgramType> types = root.join("programType");
Join<ProgramType, Specialization> special = types.join("specializations");
Join<Specialization, Solution> solution = special.join("solutions");

return cb.equal(solution.get("name"), value);
```